# How to inject a ViewModel into a composable function using Hilt (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: mvvm, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I'm doing the same as shown in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt).
I want to Inject the ViewModel into a Composable function (Screen), but I get this error:

> Cannot create an instance of class
> com.example.blotube.ui.later.LaterViewModel

**My ViewModel:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class LaterViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val database: Database
):ViewModel() {

    val watchLater=database.videos().getAll()

}
```

**My Composable Function (Screen):**

```
@Composable
fun WatchLater(vm: LaterViewModel = viewModel()){


    val videos=vm.watchLater.observeAsState()
    val context= LocalContext.current
    

}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From version `androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha02`
you can inject view model into **Composable** functions by:

```
hiltViewModel<ViewModelType>()
```

Example:

```
@Composable 
fun LoginScreen(viewModel: LoginViewModel) {}

LoginScreen(
    viewModel = hiltViewModel<LoginViewModel>()
)
```

[Android Developer Documentation compose and hilt](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt)

**UPDATE:**

```
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel

@Composable 
fun LoginScreen(
    viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()
){
   val videos=vm.watchLater.observeAsState()
   val context= LocalContext.current
}
```

Comment: Simply use inside compose
exampleViewModel: ExampleViewModel = viewModel()

Comment: seems hiltViewModel() isn't available anymore

Comment: Following your setup I got the following error: `CreationExtras must have a value by SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`

Comment: Can you provide an example with `@AssistedInject`?

Comment: check this @desgraci https://medium.com/scalereal/providing-assistedinject-supported-viewmodel-for-composable-using-hilt-ae973632e29a

Comment: I tried doing this but the init function of the viewmodel is never called. Did someone else get this issue?

Answer (score 10):

I find the simplest way to do it is inside your composable function.
Add the dependency `implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'` then;

```
@Composable 
fun Foo(){
    val viewModel : Bar = hiltViewModel()
}
```

then you can use the viewmodel as usual.

Answer (score 9):

You can use ViewModel directly inside Composable function via **hiltViewModel()**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun WatchLater(vm: LaterViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {

  val videos = vm.watchLater.observeAsState()
  val context = LocalContext.current

}
```

Please make sure to add following

1. Adding **androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose** dependency to your module level Gradle file. Do check for latest version(tested on 1.0.0-alpha03).
2. **@HiltViewModel** to your ViewModel.
3. **@AndroidEntryPoint** for the owner using the Composable function.

Comment: I am getting hiltViewModel() as an unresolved reference

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a bug in Jetpack Compose, will probably need to wait for an update on the Jetpack libraries to address it.

As a possible workaround, you could instantiate the viewmodel in your activity and pass it to your composable function

```
val viewModel: LaterViewModel = viewModel(
    "later_viewmodel",
    factory = defaultViewModelProviderFactory
)
WatchLater(viewModel)
```

if you are using the Nav graph component you can also scope your viewmodel to the nav graph using

```
val viewModel: LaterViewModel = hiltNavGraphViewModel<LaterViewModel>()
WatchLater(viewModel)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I think scoping the view model to the nav graph is my best solution for now.

Answer (score 2):

base document [Inject Hilt In Composable Function](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt)

*Note: notice to import class*

Sample you can used **viewModel()**

Example:

```
...
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
...
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
) { /* ... */ }
```

Full Example:

```
...
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
...
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val repository: ExampleRepository
) : ViewModel() { /* ... */ }

@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
) { /* ... */ }
```