# Chats Screen wont update when I send the message

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am having trouble updating the chats list after clicking the send button.

I can see that in the Realtime Database messages are added successfully, plus when I change the screen and then again go back to the Chats Screen those sent messages are now displayed on the screen.

Here is the **viewModel**

```
fun getMessages(senderRoom: String) {
        db.child("Chats").child(senderRoom).child("messages")
            .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    listOfMessages.clear()
                    for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
                        val message: Messages? = ds.getValue(Messages::class.java)
                        listOfMessages.add(message!!)
                        _messages.value = listOfMessages
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
                }
            })
    }
```

here are **Composable functions**

**1)** for **messages**

```
@Composable
fun ChatMessages(
    vm: ChatViewModel = viewModel(),
    userId: String? = null,
    senderRoom: String
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.DarkGray),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp)
    ) {
        items(vm.messages.value) { message ->
            ChatBubble(
                message = message,
                userId = userId!!
            )
        }
    }
}
```

and this is for **sending a message**

```
@Composable
fun SendMessageBar(
    vm: ChatViewModel = viewModel(),
    senderRoom: String,
    receiverRoom: String
) {

    var textValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = textValue,
            onValueChange = { textValue = it },
            label = { Text(text = "Type your message...") },
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )

        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                vm.sendMessage(textValue.text, senderRoom, receiverRoom)
                textValue = TextFieldValue("")
            }
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Send,
                contentDescription = "Send Message"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using

```
items(vm.messages.value) { message ->
```

in the Compose code. What you need is to subscribe to the state, so every time you send the message ViewModel should update the state in the `sendMessage`  function.
When you go back and forth you see the updated list because you fetch the fresh data and display the new value but this is an imperative approach.

This codelab will help: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state#5
and also the answer here: [How to inject a ViewModel into a composable function using Hilt (Jetpack Compose)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67180046/how-to-inject-a-viewmodel-into-a-composable-function-using-hilt-jetpack-compose)