# How to correctly create ViewModel in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I looked up an official example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavHostController) {

  val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

  class ExampleState {
    val counter = flow {
      var count = 0
      while (true) {
        emit(count++)
        delay(200)
      }
    }.stateIn(
      scope,
      SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
      initialValue = 0
    )
  }

  val state = remember { ExampleState() }
  val count by state.counter.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
  Text(text = "$count")

}
```

It works fine, the number displayed on the screen keeps increasing.

But when I use `ViewModel`, it has a problem.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavHostController) {

  val viewModel = HomeViewModel()

  val count by viewModel.counter.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

  Text(text = "$count")

}

class HomeViewModel: ViewModel(){
  val counter = flow {
    var count = 0
    while (true) {
      emit(count++)
      delay(200)
    }
  }.stateIn(
    viewModelScope,
    SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
    initialValue = 0
  )
}
```

I observed that the numbers on the screen were blinking constantly, but always showing `0`. It seems that Compose is constantly reorganizing, but State has not changed?

What did i do wrong?

#### edit first

**This is such a low-level question, I forgot.**

Comment: The problem is that you always create a new view model on each recomposition. `val viewModel = HomeViewModel()`. You should use `val viewModel : HomeViewModel = viewmodel()`

See: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state?hl=vi#5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewModel` must be owned by `ViewModelStoreOwner`. You are creating the viewModel manually which is not managed and reused by `ViewModelStore`.

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
// reference to the ViewModel
  val viewModel = viewModel<HomeViewModel>()

  val count by viewModel.counter.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

  Text(text = "$count")

}

class HomeViewModel: ViewModel(){
  val counter = flow {
    var count = 0
    while (true) {
      emit(count++)
      delay(200)
    }
  }.stateIn(
    viewModelScope,
    SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
    initialValue = 0
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to go with a Hilt based solution for injecting ViewModels into Composables. I believe this question has already been asked before on StackOverflow. There is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67943464/12333099). Essentially, your result will then look something like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
  // ...
}
```

as per the current documentation: [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation). This way, you won't need to worry about the injection yourself. Hope that helps.