# How to squeeze a Camera Preview in a Box?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to limit the size the CameraPreview takes up on screen:

```
@Composable
fun ShopView(analyzer: ImageAnalysis) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(10.dp)) {
        CameraPreview(analyzer)
    }
}

@Composable
fun CameraPreview(analyzer: ImageAnalysis) {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    AndroidView(factory = { context ->
        val previewView = PreviewView(context).apply {
            scaleType = PreviewView.ScaleType.FILL_CENTER
            implementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE
        }

        ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context).apply {
            addListener({
                val cameraProvider = this.get()
                val preview = androidx.camera.core.Preview.Builder().build().apply {
                    setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)
                }

                try {
                    cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        lifecycleOwner,
                        CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA,
                        analyzer,
                        preview
                    )
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
        }
        previewView
    })
}
```

That does'nt work though. The CameraPreview seems to think it's ought more space. On top of the Camera Preview there're actually some tabs, which the CameraPreview manage to supersede. I didn't think this possible, since the CameraPreview is essentially inside a Column, beneath the tabs:

```
@Composable
fun MainView(analyzer: ImageAnalysis) {
    var tabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val tabs = stringArrayResource(id = R.array.tabs)

    Column {
        TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = tabIndex,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
        ) {
            tabs.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(
                    text = { Text(title) },
                    selected = tabIndex == index,
                    onClick = { tabIndex = index },
                    icon = {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(
                                id = when (index) {
                                    0 -> R.drawable.baseline_shopping_cart_24
                                    1 -> R.drawable.baseline_format_list_bulleted_24
                                    2 -> R.drawable.baseline_leaderboard_24
                                    else -> R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground
                                }
                            ),
                            contentDescription = title
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        when (tabIndex) {
            0 -> ShopView(analyzer)

        }
    }
}
```

How does the CameraPreview manage to bust out of the constraints surrounding it?

How can I effectively limit the space the CameraPreview takes up on screen?

Ideally I would like the height of the CameraPreview to be maxWidth * 3 / 4. The static 10.dp in my code is just work in progress.

(Oh, and if somebody could give me a hint on how to untangle this code so that I don't have to pass the analyzer through like this, that would be appreciated.)

Comment: I actually had a similar problem today at work, with an transformable image in a Column 
If you replace the Column with a Box and align your tabbar on the top it works fine: Why it works? I have no clue. ChatGPT said something about that Android Views are rendered above Compose UI but I'm not sure about that. 
To untangle your analyser I would suggest you to put it into a viewmodel and inject it into the camera preview

Comment: ... and inject it into the camera preview - could you please expand on that? What do mean by 'inject'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67180046/how-to-inject-a-viewmodel-into-a-composable-function-using-hilt-jetpack-compose
Have a look here. You basically delegate the instantiation of the ViewModel Object to another place in your program to not to be bothered by it. That can be as simple as just defining it outside your code where you want to use it and then passing it as a parameter, or if you use a library like Hilt, then Hilt will take care of creating the needed objects. That entire pattern is called dependency injection.